# how to get string between two dots in ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

this is part of my ansible hosts files:

```
[Arista]
Ars-898z.cnd0 arista_host=Ars-898z.cnd0.example.com
Ars-898y.mex0 arista_host=Ars-898y.mex0.exmaple.com
```

I want to somehow use filtering or regex to extract only cnd or mex (the string between first and second dot) in my ansible playbook and save it a variable such as "dcname" and use it create a folder.

Please let me know how I can do it. I have already searched stackoverflow but did not get any similar questions for ansible

Comment: The strings `cnd0` and `mex0` are between second and third dot. Did you mean the long part or the short part?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
(?<=\.)[^.]+(?=\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iqAhp7/1).

---

Here is a more flexible solution:

```
(?<=\.)[^.]+(?=(?:\.[^.]*){3}$)
```

The `3` can be adjusted. It is the number of dots `'.'` that come after the matched substring. If you enter `2`, you get `"cnd0"`, if you enter `3`, you get `"cnd0 arista_host=Ars-898z"`.

Another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iqAhp7/6).

Comment: The extension occurs twice, so imo [**`^[^.]+\.(\S+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/iqAhp7/3) would suffice and needs only a fraction of steps compared to the other solution.

Comment: @Jan True, but I wanted to match the interesting substring as `group(0)`, not as `group(1)`, and I wanted to avoid look-behinds, so I've counted the `'.'`-dots after the matched string.

Comment: You wanted to *avoid look-behinds* ? And what exactly is `(?<=...)` ???

Comment: @Jan I meant non-fixed length lookbehinds. The `(?<=\.)` has fixed length `1`. Some regex engines (don't ask me which ones) support fixed-length lookbehinds, but not arbitrary lookbehinds.